# pushViewController not doing anything (Following IAP tutorial)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, in-app-purchase, pushviewcontroller

I was following a tutorial to add in-app purchases to my iOS app (here's the tutorial for reference: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_In-App_Purchase_Tutorial) but I have an issue I can't seem to find a solution to.

When using `[nav pushViewController:_purchaseController animated:YES];`, nothing happens: the view stays the same, nothing happens on the screen whatsoever. The rest of the code in the methods seems to work without too much of an issue, but there must be an issue before that, which I believe is with the `_purchaseController` because it seems that everything about it is nil.

There was also an issue with `self.navigationController` which was nil, so I replaced it with `nav`, which is declared the line before (`UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self];`). So maybe there's an issue here as well, I'm not really sure.

Here's the related code:

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>
#import "ViewControllerPurchase.h"
#import "ViewControllerPlay.h"
#import "ViewControllerWon.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic) ViewControllerPurchase *purchaseController;

- (IBAction) unwind:(UIStoryboardSegue *)unwindSegue;
- (IBAction) openReviewApp:(id)sender;
- (IBAction) purchaseIncreaseCap:(id)sender;

- (void) increaseAttemptCap;

@end
```

**ViewController.m** (beginning of it, rest is not related)

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _purchaseController = [[ViewControllerPurchase alloc] init];

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:_purchaseController];
}

- (IBAction)purchaseIncreaseCap:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Clicked increase button");

    _purchaseController.productID = @"MM3X3IAC099";

    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self];

    [nav pushViewController:_purchaseController animated:YES];

    [_purchaseController getProductInfo: self];
}
```

It's the first time I ever used .xib files in my project, as I'm fairly new to all of this, so it might be just a really simple mistake, but I can't seem to spot it, even after quite a bit of research. Hopefully some of you guys can be kind enough to indicate where I'm doing something wrong, or refer me to something that could help me with the issue.

**EDIT**

After adding a NavigationController to the ViewController on which the purchase button is, self.navigationController does work but it still doesn't show anything. After `[self.navigationController pushViewController:_purchaseController animated:YES];` nothing changes on the screen, it never reaches the "viewDidLoad" of the `ViewControllerPurchase` and the application crashes, on `0x2e5b9c6e:  trap` with the error `Thread 1: EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xdefe)` :/

Comment: is ViewController inside a NavigationController?

Comment: @Infinity I thought it was but it wasn't but it's still not working after fixing that. (look at the edit to my post)

Answer (score 2):

In the simplest setup, the view controller you are pushing from (class defined as ViewController in your code) is contained within a navigation controller.

Then your first attempt, `self.navigationController` will work fine.  Just do:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:_purchaseController animated:YES];
```

But because `self.navigationController == nil`, it means the ViewController instance is not contained in a navigation controller.  You can do that in storyboard or in code.  You might need to post more in your question about how the *from* view controller is setup.

In a more unusual setup, you might present a navigation controller above a vc not contained by a navigation controller.  That would look like this (but don't do this unless you're sure it's what you mean):

```
// note the different root
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_purchaseController];

// note the present, not push
[self presentViewController:_purchaseController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

For this in your story board, select the viewController from which you have to navigate, now go to editor -> embed In -> navigation controller.

Also now you can remove the code written in your button's action for making a navigation controller.

Try this code:

```
yourViewController *VC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourViewControllerId"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:VC animated:YES];
```

Comment: I just tried that, but it still doesn't show anything. After `[self.navigationController pushViewController:_purchaseController animated:YES];` nothing changes on the screen, it never reaches the "viewDidLoad" of the ViewControllerPurchase and the application crashes, on `0x2e5b9c6e:  trap` with the error `Thread 1: EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xdefe)`
:/

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this :

```
  - (IBAction)purchaseIncreaseCap:(id)sender
  {
     NSLog(@"Clicked increase button");

    _purchaseController.productID = @"MM3X3IAC099";

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:_purchaseController animated:YES];
    [_purchaseController getProductInfo: self];
  }
```